# How to add a field value from infopath form into a URL Link within that same Infopath form?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have an InfoPath 2010 form and within it I am trying to create a dynamic link.I have tried a few ways including adding a hyperlink and attempting to call a field called "filename" but it keeps leading to a blank page.
The other approach was to try and add the "filename"to the end of a URL but I don;t know how to call the "filename" or the proverbial ID value ) in InfoPath as you would in SharePoint Designer.
How do I grab the "field name" value and add it to the URL? So That I can make it dynamic using the field name as the parameter?